# How to create a variable based on another variable

Tags: xml, xslt

I am learning xsl and I have some questions about variables. If I have a variable 
    
These would load the $Rows variable with some rows based on the conditions... However I would like to create a new variable from $Rows called $newRows just with rows where column @States are equal to "Florida." 
Is that possible and how should I do that. 
I thought about creating a variable and populate it using a for-each loop like:
    
       
         
       
    
Is this possible and if is how can I populate the values into the new variable.
Thank you

Comment: These are the code I couldn't add to the previous question`<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="../Rows/Row/some condition"/>

    <xsl:variable name="newRows>
    <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
    <xsl:value-of ....../>
    </xsl:for-each>`

Answer (score 1):

As long as the condition can be expressed as an XPath predicate I suggest to simply use `<xsl:variable name="filteredRows" select="$Rows[@States = 'Florida']"/>`.